# How to decrement a value in Parse cloud using iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Maybe this question is very basic but I am looking for a nice way to decrement a value. I have a column called "credit" in _User table. Default value is 0. I want to decrement one credit from this column. This is what I have so far:

```
            //Decrement user credit
            let query2 = PFQuery(className:"_User")
            query2.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
            query2.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error != nil
                {
                    PFUser.currentUser()!["credit"] = (PFUser.currentUser()!["credit"] as! Int) - 1
                    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To decrement, and also increment, a particular field, Parse has some built-in methods:

- `object.incrementKey("key")`
- `object.incrementKey("key", byAmount: 2) // any int amount`
- `object.decrementKey("key")`
- `object.decrementKey("key", byAmount: 2) // any int amount`

So after fetching your user object in that query, your code will become:

```
PFUser.currentUser().incrementKey("credit")
PFUser.currentUser().saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if (success) {
    // The credit key has been incremented
  } else {
    // There was a problem, check error.description
  }
}
```

See Parse documentation [here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-counters) on Counters.

Comment: It seems that decrementKey has been removed. I can't find/use it anymore with current Parse iOS/Swift SDK

Answer (score 1):

```
object.decrementKey("key", byAmount: myIntValue)
```

has been removed from Parse SDK methods (at least with iOS). The doc isn't up-to-date anymore.

You can now decrement by incrementing with a negative value, like this :

```
object.incrementKey("key", byAmount: NSNumber(value: -1 * myIntValue))
```